# Validation Rule Formula

Tags: validation

Hello I am new to salesforce, I have to put a validation rule on a custom field (Deposit Date), There are 2 conditions:
1-Deposit date not exceed the current date
2-Deposit date not before 26 of previous month

Comment: Hi @Atul, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help), scroll through the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: For questions like these (you are just starting to learn a specific part of Salesforce), it's usually better to see if there is anything that can help you over on Trailhead. Trailhead is much better suited for teaching the basics, and there is [a module on validation rules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/validation_rules).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below formula, It should work : -

```
AND( 
Deposit_date__c > TODAY(), 
Deposit_date__c <DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,26) 
)
```

Comment: There a fair chance of today being a date on January where you need to check against '26-Dec-Previous year'.

Comment: Its not working yet

Comment: For what scenario it is not working?

Comment: when i submit next date to current date it not show any error